# Exit looping program

Tags: windows

Sorry guys, I know this must have been asked a hundred times and I've tried some of the suggstions with no luck.

I'm stuck in a loop in the Windows Recovery process. The program runs until the last step "Setup is starting services". It can't and I know why. I'm a gamer (flying) and I use a program that stops unneccesary background srvices. I probably didn't restore to "work" mode before I started the recovery process and so they can't be started.

Anyway, when I start in command mode, after the list of files being opened stops scrolling, it immediately goes to "Setup is starting services" again.

I've tried Ctrl+C, and I don't even know if I did that right because all I see is the message.

Be compassionate and help a dummy will ya.

Comment: I presume safe mode does not work?

Comment: It works and goes directy back to "Setup is starting services"

Answer (score 0):

If it is A program that you start AFTER you log in to your computer. Hold down `Control+Alt+Delete` then release them. A few items should pop up. Click " Start Task Manger"  If you are not already on the tab labeled "processes", click on it. In the list look for the process you want to stop click on it, click "End Process" Then Yes if any pop-ups appear. Hoped this helped.